# Can't change button innerHTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find a way to change the string "FIND NOW" into something else.
I have tried for hours

```
<button type="submit" class="qbutton  default" style="">FIND NOW</button>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<script>
  document.getElementsbyClassName('.button.qbutton.default').innerHTML('change it!');
</script>
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: Go read up on how getElementsbyClassName works … it returns a collection, not a single element, so you have to access one of those elements inside the collection first.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('qbutton default')[0].innerHTML = 'change it!'` read [DOCs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) before posting questions

Comment: Also your button in the selector doesn't want a dot before it as you don't have a class of button

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('qbutton default')[0].innerHTML="change it";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector('button.qbutton.default')` as `querySelector()` will allow you to select the particular element based on the selector and not list of elements. Also you need to use `button` as selector and not `.button` and make sure the `script` is after the `body` element to get the HTML rendered properly first.

```js
document.querySelector('button.qbutton.default').innerHTML = 'change it!';
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="qbutton  default" style="">FIND NOW</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It still doesn't work on my page though. How is that possible? My JS is enclosed between script tags.

Comment: @JohnWilver You can create a JSFiddle or Plunkr for that and link here

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('button.qbutton.default').innerHTML = 'change it!';
  </script>
  <body>
    <button type="submit" class="qbutton  default" style="">FIND NOW</button>
  </body>

</html>`

Comment: @JohnWilver you need to specify the `script` after `body` tag like ```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Testing</title>
 </head> 

  <body> 
  <button type="submit" class="qbutton default" style="">FIND NOW</button> 
  </body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('button.qbutton.default').innerHTML = 'change it!'; 
</script>
  </html>```

Comment: @JohnWilver answer is also updated

Comment: Thanks, my brain is cooked today.  Cheers